# If I use renderTemplate how to refresh route in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My two routes have the same template and controller so my route want to use renderTemplate the same template and controller, like:

```
OrderRoute = Ember.Route.extend 
  model: (params)->  
    Product.findAll(params)

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    @controllerFor('product').set('model', model)

  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'products',
      controller: 'products'

  actions:
    queryParamsDidChange: ->
      @refresh()
```

The controller:

```
ProductController = Ember.Controller.extend
  queryParams: ['number']

  number: null
```

The code look like is no problem, but when I use I found the `query params` could not work.

jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gegonemadu/1/edit

I could not google anything about this question.

I knew if I use `OrderRoute` and `OrderController` the route and controller have same name, all the think will be ok. But I my 2 route want to have the same template, just like:

> /order
>   /other
>   2 route url use the `product` template and controller

I am using `{{partial}}` to this, just like: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bifanateku/1/edit?html,js,console

This is can work, but I think if I can use `renderTemplate` the code will be cleaner.

Maybe there is any better way to approach this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by `query params` could not work?

Comment: Please provide a minimal demo of the problem via https://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: @code-jaff I add the jsbin. Not work is mean when I change the `query params`, the url did not change and did not refresh the route.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov Thanks. I already add. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dayotavagu/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For query params, the controller and the route should work together.

In your case, you're using the `order` route which expects query params from an `order` controller which you don't have.

So you either define a different controller for the route, e. g.

```
contollerName: 'product',
```

or move the query params definition to the `order` controller and bind them to properties of the `product` controller.

This is a hairy set up, I believe you might be [doing something wrong](http://xyproblem.info/) in the first place.

### Update 1

You should not use controllers for that. Use components.

Ember is deprecating controllers and going to use only components. But for now, controllers are still necessary as entry points for your pages. The rest should be components!

Here's how you should do it:

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
  this.route('bar')
});


App.FooController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['number'],
  number: null
});


App.BarController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['number'],
  number: null
});
```

```html
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
    {{x-product number=number}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bar">
    {{x-product number=number}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/x-product">
    Search Product:
    {{input value=number}}

    <ul>
      {{#each model}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xixeto/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks. I knew if I set the route and controller same name, all the thing will be ok. But I want to do this, because my two route must use the same template, but the route name not the same  Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gegonemadu/1/edit

Comment: Now I see, maybe use components is best way to solve this problem.